# Small hardware for linux?

Tags: linux, mysql, hardware-rec

Can anyone recommend some hardware which meets the following criteria:

- USB port (more than 1 would be handy but an USB hub could always be used)
- Suitable for running a reasonably small linux distribution (no gui needed. Want to run mysql and some other custom bits. I'm not quite sure how one goes about installing linux and configuring on a device without a video out? )
- Reasonably small (thinking a small router)
- Low power consumption (less than 10W. Ideally closer to 1W)

Just a little background- I'm currently working on some home automation projects and having some usb/serial devices I want to capture data from and log to mySQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the $25 [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) which is scheduled to be available in January 2012?

Comment: interestingly that was on the frontpage of a forum i visit earlier (although the forum has very little to do with home automation- so it's entirely coincidental)- looks very promising although i'm very impatient! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Plug PC's](http://www.plugcomputer.org/)? If your looking spesificly for home automation check the [Stratus](http://www.plugcomputer.org/development-kits/stratus.html). It has Zwave and ZigBee built in. You could combine that with a [Tweet-a-Watt](https://www.adafruit.com/products/143) or any other ZigBee project you may have in mind.

Comment: Thanks- they look interesting. For those without video output (stratus/sheevaplug etc) how would I go about installing linux to a point where I could SSH in?

Answer (score 1):

The different Alix boards from http://pcengines.ch/alix.htm are another possibility.